# Need suggestions for improving startup performance of my Linux project

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian, lubuntu

I'm working on a project and am having some trouble understanding the best way to deliver it. The project consists of a webapp that I've written and will be used on older/surplus computers. The idea is to package this app up with a Linux distro and either install it on these computers or run it off a live USB. Basically, when you turn the computer on it should load the operating system, automatically start the web app, launch a browser and point it at the web app. That's all it needs to do. Sort of like a  kiosk application, although the user should have full control over the browser unlike a kiosk.

I've prototyped this on a Raspberry Pi 4  (2GB memory) running the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS. Once the device is turned on, it takes about 43 seconds until the web app shows up in the browser. I consider this to be reasonable performance.

I then tried to run the same thing on an old Intel i5 computer with 4GB of memory running the latest version of Lubuntu (clean install). I chose Lubuntu because I understand *Ubuntu the best, and I believe that Lubuntu is the "Leanest" flavor. What I experienced I can't explain. It took 2:44 for the system to come up completely, a whole 2 minutes longer than the far less powerful RPi.

Here's what I found:

```
                     RPi      Lubuntu

POST                 0:10       0:06
Splash Screen        NONE       0:28
Desktop Init         0:20       1:59
Browser launches     0:39       2:40
Ready                0:43       2:44
```

I don't know Linux well enough to understand what's happening that's taking so long, and more importantly, what I can do to try and get better performance. Do I start trying to rip things out? This was a clean install of Lubuntu so there's not a lot there. Of course, all I really need is my web app and a browser. Should I try a different distro, and if so, which one? I want excellent performance for both the installed as well as the Live USB case.

## Thanks for any help or suggestions you can offer.

## Update 1

Edit: Adding output from systemd-analyze

```
17.622s dev-sda1.device
 12.457s snapd.service
 12.221s udisks2.service
 11.998s networkd-dispatcher.service
 11.341s accounts-daemon.service
  9.977s ModemManager.service
  9.226s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  8.385s systemd-journal-flush.service
  7.349s NetworkManager.service
  7.258s thermald.service
  6.689s apport.service
  6.525s e2scrub_reap.service
  6.353s apparmor.service
  5.832s grub-common.service
  5.803s rsyslog.service
  5.267s avahi-daemon.service
  5.067s systemd-logind.service
  5.048s wpa_supplicant.service
  5.043s ofono.service
  5.032s grub-initrd-fallback.service
  4.653s plymouth-quit.service
  4.652s setvtrgb.service
  4.519s colord.service
  4.503s gpu-manager.service
  3.919s upower.service
  3.520s systemd-resolved.service
  2.734s pppd-dns.service
  2.625s systemd-udev-trigger.service
```

The device that I'm running this on is not a server, it's my mother-in-law's old had-me-down laptop, probably 6 or 7 years old. It's an ideal test machine because it is representative of the types of machines that will be used for this project (e.g. we get what we get and can't control the specs).

Looks like it has an old slow hard drive which won't be swapped out. Where can I get the most bang for the buck in stopping services - all I really need is Ethernet, Wifi, my web app and a browser.

## =======
Update 2

I took the suggested advise and ran systemd-analyze blame to try and figure out what processes were taking so long. I posted the results above. I then went through the exercise of figuring out which services were unnecessary for my needs and disabled them. Here's a list of what I found:

```
ModemManager.service
snapd.service
snapd.autoimport.service 
snapd.core-fixup.service 
snapd.seeded.service       
snapd.system-shutdown.service      
avahi-daemon.service
ofono.service
accounts-daemon.service 
bluetooth.service
pppd-dns.service
```

I then re-ran startup and verified that the services I stopped were missing and they were. Unfortunately, startup times didn't seem to budge. Here are the numbers:

```
                                        Stripped Down
                     RPi      Lubuntu      Lubuntu

POST                 0:10       0:06       0.06
Splash Screen        NONE       0:28       0:28
Desktop Init         0:20       1:59       1:56
Browser launches     0:39       2:40       2:38
Ready                0:43       2:44       2:42
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
 20.443s dev-sda1.device
 10.809s networkd-dispatcher.service
  9.951s udisks2.service
  8.997s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  7.976s NetworkManager.service
  6.407s rsyslog.service
  6.405s thermald.service
  6.210s grub-initrd-fallback.service
  5.978s systemd-logind.service
  5.953s wpa_supplicant.service
  5.952s apport.service
  5.952s grub-common.service
  5.833s e2scrub_reap.service
  5.177s gpu-manager.service
  3.930s systemd-journal-flush.service
  3.928s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  3.668s upower.service
  3.652s systemd-resolved.service
  3.611s systemd-udevd.service
  3.475s apparmor.service
  2.725s systemd-udev-trigger.service
  2.184s ssh.service
  1.904s systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service
  1.159s systemd-sysctl.service
   818ms systemd-rfkill.service
   807ms systemd-modules-load.service
   684ms systemd-sysusers.service
   681ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   663ms user@1000.service
   631ms keyboard-setup.service
   583ms systemd-timesyncd.service
```

All of the services that I disabled are missing from the list and the times for each remaining service aren't so different from the original. But... startup time didn't really change. What is going on here??

Comment: Can you include the output of *sudo systemd-analyze blame*? You can also cut quite a bit of time off by disabling a bunch of stuff that you don't really need. See [here](https://askmeaboutlinux.com/2019/11/28/how-to-speed-up-boot-time-on-linux-if-it-boots-slowly/) for more info.

Comment: My Ubuntu server reboots and starts its Apache server in  a matter of seconds, with 1GB memory and a single core. Are you using a SSD or an old clunky HDD? Otherwise see `systemd-analyze blame` and check the logs `dmesg`).

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions. I've adding the output. What do you think can go? I probably don't need snap or modem stuff. What else? I still need networking.

Comment: @xenoid - Updated with new information. Executive summary: took the advice but the results don't make sense.

Comment: You can repeat the exercise for all the userspace processes launched by the desktop. I would also use `free` to see how much memory is left once the desktop is launched: not much would indicate possible swapping during the boot process.